# k value-continuous error. Basic model training question

Tags: python, knn, training-data

I'm trying to build a real basic Machine Learning model based on the valuation metrics of the S&P 500. I'm trying to create a model that relates the metrics of Price/Earnings, Earning/Share, Price/Sales, Price/Book to price. My hope is that I can enter the metrics and the model returns a reasonable Price based on the metrics. This model is just for me to improve my skills and comprehension of python and data analysis. This model will not be used for any investment purposes.

I'm hung up on trying to create a visualization of an accurate K value. the code I have is below.

```
k_range=list(range(2,30))
scores= []
for k in k_range: 
    knn= KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
    knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred= knn.predict(X_test)
    scores.append(metrics.accuracy_scores(y_test,y_pred))
    

plt.plot(k_range,scores)
plt.xlabel('Value of k for KNN')
plt.ylabel ('Accuracy Score')
plt.title ('Accuracy Scores for Values of k of k-nearest-Neighbors')
plt.show
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-ee13fe0909ac> in <module>
      3 for k in k_range:
      4     knn= KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)
----> 5     knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
      6     y_pred= knn.predict(X_test)
      7     scores.append(metrics.accuracy_scores(y_test,y_pred))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py in fit(self, X, y)
   1142             self.outputs_2d_ = True
   1143 
-> 1144         check_classification_targets(y)
   1145         self.classes_ = []
   1146         self._y = np.empty(y.shape, dtype=np.int)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    168                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:
--> 169         raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
    170 
    171 

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

The error I run into is described as " ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' ".

My question is what is causing this error and how can I overcome it?

Thank you for all the help and guidance.

Comment: in which line the error occurs? please include the stacktrace

Comment: The error occurs on line number 5. I will re-edit the main post with the proper stack tracing.

Comment: what about your `y_train`? It says your `y_train` is `continuous`, which is why your model can't handle the data. Please also provide some sample of your data so we know exactly what is going on